# How to make programs be aware of network connection provided by USB tethering

Tags: usb, tethering, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android USB reverse tethering: How to fool the apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14046/android-usb-reverse-tethering-how-to-fool-the-apps)

I use USB tethering to connect my HTC Hero to a computer. And the cellphone can surf the Internet through the computer. But some programs cannot find the network connection. I can ping any IP address on the Internet in ConnectBot, which means the connection doesn't have a problem. I think it's due to some options not being toggled that makes these stupid programs not being able to find the connection. More specifically, the notice is:

> Connection failed
>
> This application requires network
>   access. Enable mobile network or Wi-Fi
>   to download data.

How can I make these programs use the USB connection rather than mobile network or Wi-Fi?

Comment: can you clarify whether you want to use the phone's data connection from another computer (what most people understood as tethering) or you want to use the computer's data connection from the phone (reverse tethering), since I had the impression that you might be referring to the latter.

Comment: Definitely sounds like Reverse Tethering to me. The problem you're facing here is that I don't think that reverse tethering is officially supported by Android, there are various workarounds and apps that can get it working, but as it's not an official feature apps may not even be aware it's possible, so you'd need to talk the dev of each app and request changes from them.  Have you thought about sharing the computer's connection out over wifi, that way your phone would just be connecting to a normal wifi network and everything should work as normal.